# save from the IF function the variable

Tags: r

I have functions and would like to save from the IF function the variable `"sick [i]"` to take advantage of it

```
for(i in 1:licznik){
  print_func <- function(a, b)
  {
    if(a > b)
    {

      print('wspolczynnik jest wiekszy' )

      print(sick[i])

    } 

  }

  print_func(a[i], b[i])
}
```

How to do it
?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Where do you want to "save" it? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: in order to check if I wrote the function correctly, I took the variable "sick" to print.
I would like the result that meets the assumption (a> b) i.e. sick [i], to write in the new variable

Comment: Independent of what you are trying to achieve, define the `print_function` outside of the for loop.
Guessing what you want to do, use `return` to let the function actually *return* a value which you can use afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#for-loops).

```
   out <- vector("list", length(licznik))
    for (i in seq_along(licznik)) {
      if(a[[i]] > b[[i]]) {
          print('wspolczynnik jest wiekszy')
          print(sick[[i]])
          out[[i]] <- sick[[i]]
      }
    }
    str(unlist(out))
```

Comment: result:

chr [1:5] NA NA NA "11" "41"


Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : Invalid vertex names



how to remove "NA" from the vector ?

Comment: maybe add an if statement before hand: `if(!is.na(sick[[i]]) out[[i]] <- sick[[i]]`